# java segregate output received from json and pass value to another method

Tags: java, json, rest

I am getting following output on console from the json post request in java using rest api.

```
{"id":"19494","key":"DF-1079","self":"http://sjira/rest/api/2/issue/19494"}
```

I need to take just key from this output and pass it on to other method using java.

Comment: Don't be so selfish. Write a class for de-serializing the same. And then pass the required parameters. Learn the art of inner classes for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `entrySet()` on json object and populate a `List` which can be further used as argument in a method or anywhere.

```
  JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
  JSONObject jObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(postString); // postString contains your response string

    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Entry<String, JsonElement> e : jObj.entrySet()) {
        keys.add(e.getKey());
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your response jack. i am getting compile time error here JsonObject jObj = new JsonObject(output); The constructor JsonObject(String) is undefined

Comment: this is because of the version of JSON library you are using. can i know which version you are using?

Comment: i am using jsoup-1.8.2

Comment: and json-simple-1.1

Comment: you have to use a parser. Check and let me know its working for you or not

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson library for json parsing.
This json library will convert json String to the Object you want. You want keys from it so you can get it parsed to a map and then get key set from it. Pass this key set to other method as per your need.

Code Example

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String response= "{\"id\":\"19494\",\"key\":\"DF-1079\",\"self\":\"http://sjira/rest/api/2/issue/19494\"}";
//below line will parse your response to map
Map<String,Object> map = gson.fromJson(response, Map.class);
//get keyset from it pass to some method.
passToSomeMethod(map.keySet())
```

This keyset will be of type Set. Implementation in method to use it should be accordingly.
Done